# adding new collections to same document using firestore in android studio

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on android app and when I ask a person to sign up, they can either be a `user` or a `provider`. It will then ask for things like `fname,lname,address` and so on. At the moment, I am storing new `providers` in the `demoProviders` document. The way my code is now is that whenever I create add a new `provider`, any data stored get rewritten by the new `provider`. Meaning I can only have one provider at a time. I want to create new `providers` everytime someone signs up and have it added to the same`document` but as a new `collection`. I am new to `firestore` so any help would be greatly appreciated. I will post my `UserProfileActivity` down below.

Update: Added Image of `firestore` structure
[image]

`ProviderSignUp`

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.dynamic.ObjectWrapper;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ProviderSignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String KEY_FNAME = "First Name";
    private static final String KEY_LNAME = "Last Name";
    private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "Address";
    private static final String KEY_SPINNER_VALUE = "Spinner Value";
    private static final String KEY_FIXED= "Fixed Rate";
    private static final String KEY_HOURLY = "Hourly Rate";
    private static final String KEY_AGE_VALE= "Age Value";
    private static final String KEY_DOLLAR_VALUE = "Dollar Value";
    private static final String KEY_YES_INSURED = "Insured";
    private static final String KEY_NO_INSURED = "Insured";


    private EditText fName;
    private EditText lName;
    private EditText address;
    private Spinner my_spinner;
    private RadioButton fixedRadioButton;
    private RadioButton hourlyRadioButton;
    private EditText ageEditText;
    private EditText dollarEditText;
    private RadioButton yesButton;
    private RadioButton noButton;
    private RadioGroup daGroup;
    private RadioGroup daGroup2;


    // Reference to firestore database
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.provider_signup);


        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.provider_choices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // FireStore Storage for Provider

        fName = findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lName = findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        address = findViewById(R.id.Address);
        ageEditText = findViewById(R.id.ageEditText);
        dollarEditText = findViewById(R.id.dollarEditText);

        my_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
        fixedRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.fixedRadioButton);
        hourlyRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.hourlyRadioButton);

        yesButton = findViewById(R.id.yesRadioButton);
        noButton = findViewById(R.id.noRadioButton);
        daGroup = findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
        daGroup2 = findViewById(R.id.hourlyFixedRadioGroup);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(ProviderSignUp.this,PreSignUp.class));
        finish();
    }

    // These two methods below are for the spinner in the ProviderSignUp
    @Override
    // Will show a toast message after user selects spinner item
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        String text = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    // This method will save into firestore
    public void saveInfo(View view){

        String fname = fName.getText().toString();
        String lname = lName.getText().toString();
        String my_address = address.getText().toString();
        String spinner = my_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String fixed_radioButton = fixedRadioButton.getText().toString();
        String hourly_Radiobutton = hourlyRadioButton.getText().toString();
        String age = ageEditText.getText().toString();
        String dollar = dollarEditText.getText().toString();
        String yes_button = yesButton.getText().toString();
        String no_button = noButton.getText().toString();

        // checks field if empty or not
        if(isEmptyField(fName))return;
        if(isEmptyField(lName))return;
        if(isEmptyField(address))return;
        if(isEmptyField(ageEditText))return;
        if(isEmptyField(dollarEditText))return;


        Map<String,Object> myMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        myMap.put(KEY_FNAME,fname);
        myMap.put(KEY_LNAME,lname);
        myMap.put(KEY_ADDRESS, my_address);
        myMap.put(KEY_AGE_VALE, age);
        myMap.put(KEY_DOLLAR_VALUE, dollar);
        myMap.put(KEY_SPINNER_VALUE , spinner);

        if(daGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.hourlyRadioButton){
            myMap.put(KEY_HOURLY, true);
        }else if(daGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fixedRadioButton){
            myMap.put(KEY_FIXED , true );
        }

        if (daGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.yesRadioButton){
            myMap.put(KEY_YES_INSURED, true);
        } else if (daGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.noRadioButton){
            myMap.put(KEY_NO_INSURED, false);
        }


        db.collection("demoProviders").document("First Provider")
                .set(myMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(ProviderSignUp.this, "User Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(ProviderSignUp.this,MainActivity.class));

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ProviderSignUp.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    // This method will validate if EditText fields are empty
    private boolean isEmptyField (EditText editText){
        boolean result = editText.getText().toString().length() <= 0;
        if (result)
            Toast.makeText(ProviderSignUp.this, "Fill all fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
db.collection("demoProviders").document("First Provider").set(myMap)
```

to

```
db.collection("demoProviders").document().set(myMap)
```

When using DocumentReference's [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#set(java.lang.Object)) method, it:

> Overwrites the document referred to by this DocumentReference.

So everytime you need to use another reference. As you can see in my example above, I haven't passed any argument to the [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#document()) method:

> Returns a DocumentReference pointing to a new document with an auto-generated ID within this collection.

Comment: I have also added the image of my firestore structure for reference.

Comment: There is no need for that. The problem is your reference. Please try my solution above and tell me if it works.

Comment: I am getting the error below `class R is public, should be declared in a file named R.java`

Comment: When doing what? When you simply remove the `"First Provider"` argument from the `document()` method?

Comment: Yeah as soon as I removed that I got all of these errors.

Comment: There is no way you simply remove that argument and get that error. The error is related to something else. The only thing that you need to do is to delete that `First Provider` from the `document()` method.

Comment: This is the error in the logcat `11-26 08:41:27.222 14025-14025/losdos.help4hire E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length`

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error? I'm afraid not at the one I recommended you to be changed, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184273/discussion-between-moegizzle-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex Mamo for your help!